# peewee custom field - define allowed values

Tags: python, python-3.x, peewee

Two cases:

1.) I'd like to define an attribute (val) that can take the integers 0, 1, or 2 only.

```
class Trinary(Model):
    """val should accept the values 0, 1 or 2 only"""
    val = IntegerField()
```

2.) I'd like to define an attribute (val) that can take specific strings only, for example ["strawberry", "peach", "apple"]

```
class Fruit(Model):
    """val should accept the values "strawberry", "peach" or "apple" only """
    val = ???
```

Is is possible to implement such a restriction using peewee?

Thanks for your help!

Muff

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The objects `IntegerField` etc. are classes, and can be subclassed ([documentation](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#custom-fields)):

The classes should define `db_value` to convert from python to database,
and `python_value` for the other way round

```
class TrinaryField(IntegerField):
        def db_value(self, value):
            if value not in [0,1,2]:
                raise TypeError("Non-trinary digit")
            return super().db_field(value)  # call
```

Comment: From off documentation and peewee > 3.0 actual method adapt()

Answer (score 0):

From peewee 3.0 actual method adapt() it can convert your type value to the field type.

> Imagine we have user status Enum with UserStatus

And this way we can convert Enum to int and back

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from enum import IntEnum, unique

@unique
class UserStatus(IntEnum):
    active = 0
    blocked = 1
    deleted = 2

class UserStatusField(SmallIntegerField):
    def db_value(self, status_enum_field):
        """
        Python -> DataBase
        :param value: Enum
        :return: int
        """
        if not isinstance(status_enum_field, UserStatus):
            raise TypeError("Wrong type, must be enum")
        return super().adapt(status_enum_field.value)  # call

    def python_value(self, db_val):
        """
        DataBase -> Python
        :param db_val: int
        :return: Enum
        """
        return UserStatus(db_val)
```